# Looping through values using a partial id using Selenium

Tags: selenium

I want to loop through many different values using `xpath` but for some reason my code loops over the same value over and over. In the code below using Python

```
        m = 0;
        classPREFIX = [];

        while True:
            try:
                ignored_exceptions=(NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException,);
                departmentClass = WebDriverWait(browser, 10,ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id, 'partial-id-name')]")));

                classPREFIX.append(departmentClass.text);
                print(classPREFIX[m])
                m += 1;
            except Exception:
                print("indexed outta bounds in classes prefix");
                break;
```

In the HTML there are multiple elements with partial-id-name however they have different numbers after them. For example

```
    <div
         <id = "randomText3_partial-id-name_1" >
    </div>
    <div
         <id = "randomText5_partial-id-name_2" >
    </div>
    <div>
          <id = "randomText0_partial-id-name_3" >
    </div>
```

I want to get all elements that contain `partial-id-name`, but my code only gets the first id and just keeps adding the first id to my list over and over. Any ideas on how to get it to go to the next element that contains `partial-id-name`? For clarification, the id tags are nested within `div` tags

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need small modification to your script.

```
m = 0;
classPREFIX = [];
while (m<=len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'partial-id-name')]"))):
    try:
        ignored_exceptions=(NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException);
        departmentClass = WebDriverWait(browser, 10,ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id, 'partial-id-name')]")));
        classPREFIX.append(browser.find_elements_by_xpath(("//*[contains(@id, 'partial-id-name')]"))[m].text);
        print(classPREFIX[m])
        m += 1;
    except Exception:
        print("indexed outta bounds in classes prefix");
        break;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however the code did not work. 1)FindElements should be find_elements() 2) xpath should be capitalized 3) within find_elements syntax should be find_elements((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id, 'partial-id-name')]")). I think the suggestions you had made were more Java oriented than Python. However after making those changes, I get the error that "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" for using .size() i assume. Also, using .get(m) does not append any value to classPREFIX. Any ideas on why?

Comment: I would have figured it out though you did not specified the language tag in your question. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: it worked thank you! however, you should remove  the By.xpath in line 7 because that caused errors and should instead be classPREFIX.append(browser.find_elements_by_xpath(("//*[contains(@id, 'partial-id-name')]"))[m].text);